# Huge OpenGL performance difference in Linux versus macOS, same hardware

Tags: linux, macos, performance, opengl, gpu

I'm building an OpenGL application. The only inconvenient thing it does with OpenGL is that it uses a few (5 or more) rather large (2000x2000 and larger) textures. The rest is pretty default modern OpenGL 3.3 stuff (FBO's, VBO's, IBO's, VOA's, shaders, etc). Because these textures are so large, and require some bit depth more than 8-bit, I use the `GL_R11F_G11F_B10F` internal pixel format to reduce memory (however, changing this to something simple, does not help (see bottom)).

Now, here is the thing: the very exact same code, runs on Windows, Linux and macOS (I'm using SDL as abstraction layer). The performance difference between Linux and macOS on the same hardware (my late 2011 MacBook Pro 13", Intel HD Graphics 3000 @1280x800), same compiler (`clang -O3 -mavx`), is *huge*. On macOS, my frametime is about 30ms to 80ms. However, on Linux, it is a stunning 1ms to 4ms. Again, same laptop, just rebooted in different OS. Shrinking the application window to about 600x400, lowers the frametime to 13ms on macOS. Thus, it seems that the pixel shader/rasterisation is the bottleneck (my shader indeed is pretty complex).

I must say that I had better frame times in the past on macOS (around 13ms to 20ms). So, I'm getting really suspicious after discovering this, that Apple might be "degrading" the graphics driver for the Intel HD Graphics 3000 on purpose through system updates, to push costumers to buy new products. I must say that I have been thinking about buying a new laptop, but since I discovered this, a sudden disgust raised.

Now the question: what do you think what might be happening here? Buggy driver? Apple intentionally making things slower? An unoptimised GLSL compiler included in the driver? Or maybe some bad practice in my OpenGL code in the application? Is it common for drivers to have bad support for non-8-bit texture formats?

I just hate that the application is fantastic to use in Linux, and non-pleasant in macOS. The hardware is able to do better.

---

Some tests, as requested by @BDL:

- Reducing textures in size by a factor 4 in every dimension (thus 16 times less memory, leaving us with a 500x500 texture, approximately), does not influence frame time.
- Using GL_RGB8 or GL_SRGB8 as internal format doesn't influence frame time.
- Reducing a lot of shader complexity does help: I can get it down to 8ms average when dropping a lot of computations in the fragment shader.

---

I'll try a glsl shader optimizer tomorrow: https://github.com/aras-p/glsl-optimizer
Hopefully, this helps a little.

Comment: @NicolBolas I hope you stop by :)

Comment: You should profile your app using Instruments and/or OpenGL Profiler. Is it using lots of CPU time? Is it spending lots of time in texture format conversion? You should also experiment with tweaks to your code. Your use of `GL_R11F_G11F_B10F` seems like a likely cause of problems.

Comment: Can't you narrow the performance problematic part down any further? Does, for example, using smaller texture help? Does reducing the shader complexity help? Which OpenGL calls take up all the time on MacOS?

Comment: @KenThomases: No it's clearly GPU bound.

Comment: @BDL: It's hard to tell, since OpenGL stores commands in a queue. When I swap buffers (screen & backbuffer), it just waits for the gpu to be done, and thus hides what exactly takes long. However, I added some results you asked for, to my question.

Answer (score 2):

What method exactly are you using to measure the frame rendering times? In my experiments regarding timing behaviour of various OpenGL implementations the Mesa / Intel HD drivers had about the most difficult to explain timing behaviour.

The Intel HD Graphics drivers for MacOS X are a completely different codebase (zero source code overlap!), written by a whole different development team (mostly Apple folks AFAIK).

Keep in mind that OpenGL employs an asynchronous execution model *and* that there is no hard specification on the exact timing of the buffer swap call. On Linux both AMD and NVidia OpenGL pretty much have `…SwapBuffers` block until V-Sync (if V-Sync is enabled). However I found the Mesa / Intel implementation to treat `…SwapBuffers` as just another queued command and the real block would happen only with the command queue filled up and a call being made that ultimately can be executed only after the buffer swap (like clearing the back buffer).

To cut a long story short I found the only reliable way to actually measure frame render-till-presentation¹ times by placing the `glClear` call right *after* `…SwapBuffers` (i.e. clearing for the next frame that's to come in the next iteration) and measure the time from rendering start until after that unusually placed `glClear` call.

Pure rendering times (without the presentation part) are better measured through query objects, anyway.

Answer (score -1):

It's generally hard to get to the bottom of these issues on stack overflow since we don't have access to your code but here are a few things you can try:

- Update drivers to the latest version supported by the OS.
- Open a graphic debugger and check buffer sizes, texture sizes, RAM usage, Memory usage, etc.

It might just be some timing issues that have to be sorted out between OSX and Linux, you can also get a pointer to the raw window resource with SDL and fix the issue that way.

Comment: "Update drivers"? You realize that graphics drivers are part of the OS on Mac OS, right?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "fix the timing issue"? What timing issue are you talking about?

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux Are you manually setting a framelimit or is the application just running as fast as possible?

Comment: Because you asked, I tried toggling all combinations: with/without vsync, with/without manual sleep to limit to 60fps. None had effect, frame time between 36ms and 60ms. But you should note that the application is not constantly rerendering. Only when the user is interacting with it.